# Why is my event.target data not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a function to remove a field in my form that works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

```
function activeDelete(del) {
    $('[data-delete="' + del + '"]').click(function(event) {
        deleteField(event);
    });
}

function deleteField(event) {
    if ((members - 1) >= 3) {
        members -= 1;
        var i = $(event.target).data('delete');
        console.log(i)
        var currentdiv = $('[data-div="' + i + '"]');
        currentdiv.remove();
        $("#rollWheel").val("Roll the wheel ! (" + members + " members)");
    } else {
        $('.errors').remove();
        $('#firstCard').append('<div class="errors animated fadeOut">3 participants minimum.</div>');
    }


  }

activeDelete(1);
```

I logged my `i` variable and it is `undefined` (in Chrome). I tested locally and also on my website.

What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: What is your markup? And for what element this event handler was bound?

Comment: Where is the code where you call this function?

Comment: who is `deleteField` called

Comment: Edited my post to include the click function

Comment: ... and where is `activeDelete()` called from?

Comment: Can you check, what does `$(event.target)` return ? Does it, grab the correct event and its target.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyRajan, the target was mislead. Didn't know about the currentTarget. This community is awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `currentTarget` here instead of `target`, but I recommend to you to use `$(this)`.

### The minimum change:

```
  $(event.currentTarget).data('delete');
```

### The recommended change:

```
function activeDelete(del) {
  $('[data-delete="' + del + '"]').click(function(event) {
    deleteField($(this)); // see here the parameter
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}

function deleteField(obj) {
  if ((members - 1) >= 3) {
    members -= 1;
    var i = obj.data('delete'); // see here the getter
    console.log(i)
    var currentdiv = $('[data-div="' + i + '"]');
    currentdiv.remove();
    $("#rollWheel").val("Roll the wheel ! (" + members + " members)");
  } else {
    $('.errors').remove();
    $('#firstCard').append('<div class="errors animated fadeOut">3 participants minimum.</div>');
  }


}

activeDelete(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your following line from `$(event.target)` to  `$(event.currentTarget)`. This is because the click event might have triggered on the child elements.

According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses
>   the DOM. It always refers to the element the event handler has been
>   attached to as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on
>   which the event occurred.

Or you can also change your line to `$(event.target).closest("[data-delete]")`.